# Assignment Help: List Constructors & Exceptions

Tags: java, list, exception, constructor

I am currently taking a class away from school and my professor is not helpful, so I was wondering if anyone can give me pointers on what to do. The instructions were given to me as follows:

You can create your own list class (MyList) which will be able to hold any number of items up to the actual size of the array.  Your class will maintain a counter of the actual number of items stored in the array.  The array will be of type Object so that your array can contain any Object or subclass of Object.  Your class should provide the following methods:

- `void append(Object o)` – appends the object onto the end of the list.  Throws a `ListFullException` if the list is full.
- `Object at(int index)` – returns the object at the indicated position or throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the index is not valid.
- `void remove(int index)` – remove the element at the index and moves elements after it down to fill the empty space.  Throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the index is not valid and `ListEmptyException` if the list is empty and there is nothing to remove.
- `MyList(int size)` – constructor which takes the size to make the array.

Comment: There is plenty of information already out there regarding Exceptions, how to use them, what they are etc etc.  Plenty of official docs also that go through this.  Please use google first.

Comment: I have a student class and classlist

Comment: You should indeed atleast first try yourself

Comment: I have student class and classlist. I used arraylist. but i have a feeling this should be list constructor. I have no clue actually how to start

Comment: so what I have done so far is public class student and public class classlist I have the arraylist in the classlist. add method to add students, remove method to remove students.

Comment: I sounds like you don't need help...

Comment: My question is ArrayList is good to answer this question?

Comment: @rosepetal Yes you can use arraylist. And initialize it with the size passed in your MyList Constructor.

Comment: could you give me example of void append and object at(int index)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ArrayList in underlying implementation of your MyList class.

In the constructor, use the passed size to initialize the arraylist like:

```
arrayList=new ArrayList<Object>(size);
```

In the append method, you can simply add the passed object to the arrayList(after placing size checks and throwing your ListFullException):

```
arrayList.add(obj);
```

Similarly use ArrayList's remove and get methods for remove and objectAt functionality respectively.

Comment: @rosepetal you are welcome, If you have any problems in your code, please post your code we'l help you out.